# Highcharts export server does not export labels

Tags: svg, charts, highcharts, server, export

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L6ca89dh/4/

When I export (click the hamburger and click export SVG) the Data-Labels display fine.

When I use my highcharts-export-server they do not:

[image]

*** This is how is is supposed to look:

[image]

Code snippet of chart item

```
var chart = {
title: {
  text: null
},
time: {
  useUTC: false
},
chart: {
  width: 1200,
  height: 600,
  plotBackgroundColor: null,
  plotBorderWidth: 0,
  plotShadow: false,
  spacing: 0,
        type: 'spline'
},
xAxis: {
  //startOnTick: true
},
    yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Performance (%)'
    },
    //min: 0
},      
legend: {
  enabled: true,
        navigation: false,
        itemStyle: {"fontSize": "11px", "fontWeight": "normal"}
},
rangeSelector: {
  enabled: false
},
scrollbar: {
  enabled: false
},
navigator: {
  enabled: false
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            compare: 'percent',
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
},
series: series
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that series labels are not visible on an exported image when using node export server (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server) on your side? If so, the reason behind it is because the series-label script (https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js) isn't included among other additional scripts (such as xrange) in the **build.js** file. All you need to do is to add the following:

`'{{version}}/modules/series-label.js': 1`

inside the **cdnScriptsOptional** array and run **node build.js**. For more information you can visit repo of the exporting server (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server).

Comment: I also got to the conclusion that this file was missing when toying around in jsfiddle - however I could not figure out how to "add" it to the export server. It worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @pawel_d, thank you for your reply. I already tried to include this script in build.js and rebuild it, but it still doesn't work. I use node-export-server 2.1.0, and highchart version 9.1.0.   Spend lots of time on this... Do you know something about this ?